# using dlookup in a text box

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to update the text box using dlookup when the user selects  a item in combo box, I cannot do dlookup in control source of text box since i need to store it in the table, so I am doing it in default value.

Here is the dlookup but it is not working:

> =DLookUp([Ground Clearance_inches],"tbVehicles","[Vehicle]=[Forms]![Cover Data]![vehicle]")

note that Ground Clearance_inches is number datatype in the tbVehicles table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be

```
Private Sub vehicle_AfterUpdate() 
    ''Vehicle is a number
    Me.MyTextBoxNameHere = _
       DLookUp("[Ground Clearance_inches]","tbVehicles","[Vehicle]= " _
       & [Forms]![Cover Data]![vehicle]) 

    ''Vehicle is text 
    Me.MyTextBoxNameHere = _
       DLookUp("[Ground Clearance_inches]","tbVehicles","[Vehicle]= '" _
       & Replace([Forms]![Cover Data]![vehicle], "'","''") & "'") 

    ''If the current form is [Cover Data] then 
    Me.MyTextBoxNameHere = _
       DLookUp("[Ground Clearance_inches]","tbVehicles","[Vehicle]= '" _
       & Replace(Me.[vehicle], "'","''") & "'") 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it being in the Default Value, but in VBA the where clause would be "[Vehicle]=" & [Forms]![Cover Data]![vehicle]
Why not put it in the OnUpdate event of your combo box?

Comment: is this what i need to do but it gave error:  Private Sub vehicle_AfterUpdate()
   = DLookUp([Ground Clearance_inches],"tbVehicles","[Vehicle]= " &[Forms]![Cover Data]![vehicle])
End Sub